# Read value stored in session

Tags: php, javascript, dojo

Can I from Dojo or plain JavaScript anyhow to read some value stored in session ? I stored in php in session if user is logged or not but I need to read this on my page with Dojo . Can I do that and how ?

Comment: you can echo it out to javascript or html like `var myvar = "<?php echo $_SESSION['myvar']; ?>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The session information is stored on the server. One way you can retrieve it using Dojo would be to create a PHP page that returns that variable to you and make an AJAX call from Dojo.

```
dojo.xhrGet({
    url:"getFromSession.php?var=variableToGet",
    load: function(response) {
        alert("got: " + response.responseText);
    }
})
```

And then your PHP file would look something like this:

```
<?php
    echo $_SESSION[$_GET['var']];
?>
```

Note that this will allow you to get any variable from the session. You may want to have your PHP page only return the value of a specific variable.